# jquery-notification-menu drop down not appearing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a facebook stlye notifications using a jquery plugin and I've come across http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/jquery-notification-menu/ however when I use the demo and click on the menu after adding a notification even though my count increases I do not get a drop down menu with notifications when i click on the menu.

Can anyone who is familiar with this plugin enlighten me as to why I don't get the notifications.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click on the count themselves (the red, yellow and green circles).

Comment: Agreed. I had to click around a few times.